# Magento layered navigation colors

Tags: magento, attributes, navigation, e-commerce, layer

I have a bunch of shirts in a category. A lot of them have special colors like night owl black and some that are black / red. So on and on.

I was wondering how to have them show up in layered navigation just as "black".

How would I do something that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic approach is to have two color attributes:

Navigation Color: Black, Red, Blue, Orange, Green, etc
Vendor Color: Elective Blue, Fuzzy Teal, Mystery Yellow, etc

Setup the navigation color attribute to do the filtering. The Vendor Color is what is displayed on the product detail page or anywhere it may be appropriate.

It's an added item to account for in the enrichment process but tends to work well enough.